# enum using string constants NSLinguisticTagNoun not allowed

Tags: swift, enums

Trying to define an enum with string constants but gets the compile error:

> raw value for enum case must be a literal

```
enum WordTypes: String
{
    case Noun = NSLinguisticTagNoun
    case Verb = NSLinguisticTagVerb
}
```

But NSLinguisticTagNoun is a string "Noun"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message states that the raw value must be a string **literal**. This differs from a string. A string literal is a string specified directly in the program (between quotes), not a variable of type String. See the code below:

```
"abcdef" // A string literal
let myString: String = "abcdef" // A constant of type String initialized with a string literal
myString // Not a string literal
```

NSLinguisticTagNoun and NSLinguisticTagVerb are constants of type String, not string literals. The requirement for enum raw values to be literals is a limitation in the current version of Swift. To replicate the functionality you're aiming for, you'll have to do:

```
enum WordTypes: String
{
    case Noun = "Noun"
    case Verb = "Verb"
}
```